# Specific map function inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is more question about logic here I guess. I'm trying to achieve something like that:

I have an array of four players:

```
const playersArray = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4'];
```

Every one of them plays with each other but only once, there is no rematch.

So obviously player 1 cannot play with player 1. But also there is only one match between player 1 and player 2. There is player1:player2, but we don't need to have player2:player1.

I was trying to use mapping method inside the mapping method, something like that:

```
playersArray.map(player1 => playersArray.map(player2 =>
  <ul>
    <li>{player1}</li> :
    <li>{player2</li>
  </ul>
))
```

Also avoiding scenario when a player plays with himself is pretty easy (conditional rendering). But for me the problem is to avoid rematches.

Thank you!

Comment: What you're looking for is _"all combinations of length 2"_, that should help you with Googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
playersArray.map((player, index) => 
  playersArray.slice(index+1).map(anotherPlayer => 
    (
      <ul>
        <li>{player} : {anotherPlayer}</li>
      </ul>
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is to loop over the array and create an inner loop over the rest of the array after the current index of the main loop to get all possible matches:

**Example**

```
function App() {
  const playersArray = ["player1", "player2", "player3", "player4"];
  const content = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < playersArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < playersArray.length; j++) {
      content.push(
        <div>
          {[playersArray[i]]} : {playersArray[j]}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  return <div>{content}</div>;
}
```